# Redirecting to second page in GWT doesn't load GWT components in second page

Tags: gwt, redirect, replace

i am using GWT app engine to deploy my application in local host.
i want to redirect to second page when user completed his registration & clicked "submit" button, the browser has to redirect to automatically to his Profile page with his registration details. 
i used fallowing code to redirect to second page from first page;

### String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"/UserViewProfile.html";

### Window.Location.replace(url);

in my case the first page is  URL is like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/UserRegistration.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

when i submitted on "Submit" button it is edirecting to URL like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/UserViewProfile.html
```

In second page(UserViewProfile.html) i developed simple HTML content & simple Textbox widget to check it's functionality. But i am seeing HTML content only but not "Textbox".
To see text box i has to type URL like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/UserViewProfile.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

how i can access last part **"?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997"** at end of my URL pattern automatically? if i add it manually, at the time of hosting it may leads to problem. please if any body give solution, that would be great.

Comment: Where you are not getting the textbox?? after you uploaded it to appengine or in eclipse itself?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the use case. Anyway I guess you need to conditionally check if you are in DevMode or ProdMode, and add the `gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` query string accordingly. Something like:

```
String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+ "/UserViewProfile.html";
if (GWT.isProdMode()) {
  Window.Location.replace(url);
} else {
  Window.Location.replace(url + "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
}
```

The `gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` query string parameter is used by GWT to (simplifying) bootstrap your app in the so called Development Mode, instead of the Production Mode (the actual compiled version of your application). Without this check, if you are in DevMode, you end up requesting the `UserViewProfile.html` that looks for the compiled version of your app (that does not show anything, if you've never compiled it, or if you have simply recently clean the project).

Do also note that URL rewriting (by not simply changing the `#` fragment identifier), means application reloading.